# Telerik RadButton with Awesome icon align left

Tags: css, telerik, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to set a RadButton from telerik with a awesome font Icon, but I'm not figuring out how to position the Icon the same way as the Telerik Icon

[image]

**My code:**

```
<div class="buttons-set">
              <telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="Filter" Width="110px" Skin="Default">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-filter left"></i> Filter
                </ContentTemplate>

              </telerik:RadButton>
              <telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="Clear filter" Width="110px" Skin="Default">
                  <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbCancel red" PrimaryIconLeft="6px" PrimaryIconTop="2px" />
              </telerik:RadButton>
          </div>

.left {

   text-align:left !important;
}
.red {
    color:#BC204B !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using font icons is much easier in the Lightweight RenderMode because it uses font icons for the built-in ones too

While your solution can work, there is an easier one: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/pushbutton/functionality/Icons/custom-icons#font-icons

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    button.RadButton.fa .rbIcon:before {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
    }
</style>
<telerik:RadPushButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Button With Custom Font Icon" CssClass="fa">
    <Icon CssClass="fa-bed" />
</telerik:RadPushButton>
```

Setting `RenderMode="Lightweight"` to the RadButton should let you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got this:

```
.left {  
   position:absolute !important;
   margin-right: 38px !important;
   margin-top: 3px; 
}
```